# python telethon как получить список прочитавших сообщение в группах

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

[image]

В последних версиях телеграма появилась функция где можно увидеть кто прочитал сообщение. Вопрос: Можно ли получить этот список пользователей програмно? То есть при помощи python telethon?

Цель: написать программу которая каждые 5 секунд проверяет сообщение и отмечает в чате (от имени аккаунта, не телеграм бота) всех кто прочитал. Программма на подобии юзербота.

порылся в `event.get_reply_message()` но ничего не нашел. Буду благодарен за любую поомщь!

Comment: Есть какие-нибудь идеи? Если что-то не понятно, то спрашивайте. Подскажите рабочую идею и забирайте 50 баллов